# PrimeNG MultiSelect: How to select whole group

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, multi-select

I'm using a primeNG grouped multi select and I wonder if it's possible to select all items of a group by clicking on the group itself?

Here is my code so far:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="items" [group]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" optionLabel="name" optionValue="id" optionGroupLabel="label" optionGroupChildren="subItems" (onChange)="changed()"></p-multiSelect>
```

And it gives me this:

[image]

However, I would like to have a checkbox before "Germany" where I can select all cities of "Germany" by clicking on it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the same implementation as [the docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect).

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="groupedCities" [group]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" defaultLabel="Select a City" scrollHeight="250px" display="chip">
<ng-template let-group pTemplate="group">
    <div class="p-d-flex p-ai-center">
        <img src="assets/showcase/images/demo/flag/flag_placeholder.png" [class]="'p-mr-2 flag flag-' + group.value" style="width: 20px"/>
        <span>{{group.label}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

You should be able to place a [click method](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding) on the div that contains the span

```
<div class="p-d-flex p-ai-center" (click)="selectedCities = group.items">
```

That should work, otherwise you may need to wrap it in a function

```
<div class="p-d-flex p-ai-center" (click)="setSelection(group.items)">
```

ts:

```
setSelection(items) => {this.selectedCities = items}
```